# Mirror PC display to Laptop in high quality? Using hardware solution

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Currently my PC's graphics card output is being displayed on a monitor using HDMI, basic setup.

Now I'd like to have that exact video output being mirrored onto my Laptop, the problem is that my Laptop only has an HDMI Output, no Input.

Using software solutions like TeamViewer, Parsec etc. does reduce the image quality which I would like to avoid since I want to perform Computer Vision tasks on that Laptop in realtime, so high image quality is very important to me.

Probably some hardware solution should give the best quality, but how would I be able to input that video source into my Laptop?

Both systems run Windows 10 and have HDMI ports available.

Answer (score 0):

USB-connected HDMI capture cards such as [this one](https://www.amazon.pl/Recorder-Nintendo-nagrywania-Streaming-Akcesoria/dp/B08PRX3CZX) (this is a random example from Google - I don't know if it's a good product). There are also PCI-e alternatives, but it will be hard or impossible to connect one to a laptop. Once drivers are installed, a webcam-like device streaming from the HDMI input will be detected by the system.